# Пропала подсветка в терминале, когда открываю оболочку Linux на Windows 11

Tags: wsl

Почему-то перестал подсвечиваться путь зеленым и синим, когда открываю терминал
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После ввода команд появляется такое сообщение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В чем может быть проблема или ошибка?

Comment: в powershell может открывали раньше?

Comment: @teran
Да, кажется открывала, проблема из-за этого могла возникнуть? Если да, надо что-то через powershall сделать?